# Writing to the wrong txt file c#

Tags: c#, io, streamwriter

I'm trying to write a code to write two text files.

I created two subroutines for that because they are used in diferent ocasions. But, when I run the code, insted of writing in two text files, all the info that I need to write is beeing writen in only on one file, not two.

Could you guys help me figure out what I did wrong?

I think I'm handling the Path the wrong way, but i can't figure out the proper use

```
private void COBEQ2016_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Global.Filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}__{1}", DateTime.Now, "cobeqswarm_ocresol_la_bin.txt");
    string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Global.Filename);
    File.Create(path).Close();


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Global.Filename2 = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}__{1}", DateTime.Now, "cobeqswarm_JAC_ocresol_la_bin.txt");
    string path2 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Global.Filename2);
    File.Create(path2).Close();


    //A lot of math//
double[] minX = new double[] { -3000, -400 }; 
textfile(minX, 100.0);
textfile2(minX);    


}
 public void textfile(double[] param1, double param2)
 {
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     string[] tes2 = new string[9];
     string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),Global.Filename);

     if (!File.Exists(path))
     {
         File.Create(path).Close();
         TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path,true);
         tw.WriteLine("");
         int i=0;
         while (i<param1.GetLength(0))
         {
             tw.Write(param1[i].ToString("0.000000000000000000"));
             tw.Write(" ");
             i++;
         }
         tw.Write(param2.ToString("0.000000000000000000"));
         tw.Write(" ");

         tw.Close();
     }
     else if (File.Exists(path))
     {
         TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
         tw.WriteLine("");
         int i = 0;
         while (i < param1.GetLength(0))
         {
             tw.Write(param1[i].ToString("0.000000000000000000"));
             tw.Write(" ");
             i++;
         }
         tw.Write(param2.ToString("0.000000000000000000"));
         tw.Write(" ");

         tw.Close();
     }
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 }//textfile
 public void textfile2(double[] param0)
 {
     string[] tes2 = new string[9];
     string path2 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Global.Filename2);

     if (!File.Exists(path2))
     {
         File.Create(path2).Close();
         TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path2, true);
         tw.WriteLine("");
         int i = 0;
         while (i < param0.GetLength(0))
         {
             tw.Write(param0[i].ToString("0.000000000000000000"));
             tw.Write(" ");
             i++;
         }
       //  tw.Write(param2.ToString("0.000000000000000000"));
         tw.Write(" ");

         tw.Close();
     }
     else if (File.Exists(path2))
     {
         TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path2, true);
         tw.WriteLine("");
         int i = 0;
         while (i < param0.GetLength(0))
         {
             tw.Write(param0[i].ToString("0.000000000000000000"));
             tw.Write(" ");
             i++;
         }

         tw.Write(" ");

         tw.Close();
     }
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 }//textfile2
```

Comment: Try doing some debugging

Comment: Works correctly for me. Are you changing `Global.Filename` or `Global.Filename2` somewhere else?

Comment: @cubrr No. I define then on the begginning

Comment: Doing `if (!File.Exists(path)) File.Create(path).Close();` followed by the code that writes, will reduce the amount of code by half, and avoid code duplication.

Comment: @UweKeim add some logging just like Linus would :-)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, but, for example, you can see an empty file in this case:

```
            double[] ap2 = new double[0];
            textfile2(ap2);
```

becase your loop won't work:

```
while (i < param0.GetLength(0))
```

Try to create unit tests for your methods or debug your code.

Comment: they all work. The problem is that they keep adding to the wrong file
I did some edit on the code to make a better example.
I think the problem is how I'm handling the path

Comment: your new update with "double[] minX" works fine, it looks like Global.Filename and Global.Filename2 are equal, try to hardcode different filenames in textfile() and textfile2() methods.

Comment: Yeah.. I will do that

Answer (score 0):

I created a static class for Global and solved my problens

```
static class Global
{
   private static string _globalVar = "";

   public static string Filename
   {
       get { return _globalVar; }
       set { _globalVar = value; }
   }
   private static string _globalVar2 = "";
   public static string Filename2
   {
       get { return _globalVar2; }
       set { _globalVar2 = value; }
   }
}
```